# Average by rows with sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sorting, average

I'm working with a sqlite database.
The tables are:

```
   ID_TABLE          POINTS_A_TABLE       POINTS_B_TABLE
  id   number       id_a   points_a      id_a   points_a
--------------     ----------------     ----------------
 smith   1         smith     11              ...
 gordon  22        gordon    11
 butch   3         butch     11
 sparrow 25        sparrow  
 white   76        white     46
```

and so on. After these commands

```
select id, 
    points_a_table.points_a, points_b_table.points_a, points_c_table.points_a, points_d_table.points_a
from id_table
left join points_a_table on points_a_table.id_a = id_table.id
left join points_b_table on points_b_table.id_a = id_table.id
left join points_c_table on points_c_table.id_a = id_table.id
left join points_d_table on points_d_table.id_a = id_table.id
group by id
```

I got this result, on each row I have the id and the points associated with the id.

[image]

Now I'd like to get an **average of points by row, sorted** by average in descending order. 
What I want is:

```
sparrow| 56 [(44+68)/2]
white  | 41 ([46+67+11)/3]    
smith  | 33 [(11+25+65)/3]
butch  | 24 [(11+26+11)/3]
gordon | 11 [11/1]
```

How can I do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you smush together all point tables, you can then simply compute the average for each group:

```
SELECT id,
       avg(points_a)
FROM (SELECT id_a AS id, points_a FROM points_a_table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id_a AS id, points_a FROM points_b_table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id_a AS id, points_a FROM points_c_table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id_a AS id, points_a FROM points_d_table)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY avg(points_a) DESC;
```

Comment: sorry, one more question: 
after executing your code, if I want to match the resulting column `id` with the corresponding `number` in `ID_TABLE`, how ca I do that?

The result should be:
`25|56`
`76|41`
`1|33`
and so on, thanks.

Comment: That would be a different question. (Which can be solved with a left join.)

Comment: I managed to do it by saving the previous query in a new table and joining the two tables like this: `select id_table.number, new_table_average.average
from id_table
join new_table_average on id_table.id=new_table_average.id
order by new_table_average desc ;`
Is it possible to do it without creating a new table? Directly after the code in the answer?

Comment: That would be a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). (Which can be solved with a subquery.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788025/combine-instructions-with-a-subquery-in-sqlite